# nohup - dont want nohup.out but want log going to a different file on the remote server

Tags: unix, background, ssh, nohup, logfile

I'm running the following command (where variables have valid values for ssh command and $file - is a .sql file).

```
nohup ssh -qn ${ssh_user}@${dbs} "sqlplus $dbuser/${dbpswd}@${dbname} <<ENDSQL | tee "${sql_run_output_file}".ssh.log
set echo off
set echo on
set timing on
set time on
set serveroutput on size 1000000
@${file}
ENDSQL
"
```

When I was using the above command without "nohup" before ssh command, after 1 hour or so, my connection from source server (where im running ssh) was getting an error/message "Connection reset...." and hanging my BASH shell script (which contains this ssh command in it). When, I use nohup, i dont see the connection issue.

Here's what I'm trying to get and need your help.

- Change the command shown above so that the command will NOT create a nohup.out
  (Did I read that I can use > instead of | tee ... and use 2>&1)
- I DO NOT want to run the command giving a "&" (background)
- I DO want a LOG file for the sqlplus session that's running on the target DB server via ssh command/connection (initiated from source server).

Thanks.

Comment: Is this not working for you: `nohup ssh -qn ${ssh_user}@${dbs} "sqlplus $dbuser/${dbpswd}@${dbname} <<ENDSQL > "${sql_run_output_file}".ssh.log ... ENDSQL"` ?

Comment: Not sure if I got you, but you can always get rid out output by >/dev/null

Comment: yes, > is what I can try next for getting nohup.out. As I want output instead of "no output", i can't use >/dev/null but yes, i agree.

Comment: btw, putting >/dev/null 2>&1 --- on the last line after "(double quote) didn't produce nohup.out like anu/Szilagy said

Answer (score 1):

You can still lose the connection when running `ssh` under `nohup`, so it's not really a good solution. If possible, I would recommend that you copy the sql file via `scp` to the target server, then `ssh` in to the server, open a `screen` and run the command from there (Or run it under `nohup`). Is that an option?

Comment: yep, that's whats my next plan is: Create a new script available on both source/target servers via same mount. I'll call n pass params to this new script and initiate a session via ssh: to run this new script on target (with params). New script will run sql file on target server. then i'll loop within source server script to find out the end of the file/keyword in the log file which is getting generated by the script running on target server for sqlplus session. Once I see that, I'll proceed on source server script.. until then, i'll just keep an eye via a loop every 5 secs.